# Selenium - Chrome browser just flashing

Tags: google-chrome, automation, selenium

ChromeDriver: chromedriver_win32 (Version 76.0.3809.100)
TeamCity: Windows Server 2016 Standard / 64-bit OS

I have an automated regression suite that I used to run fine in all browsers in TeamCity. Since last Friday, all the tests have started failing in Chrome because the browser just keeps flashing in short intervals and the tests do not even proceed to the login stage/visit the homepage of the system under test.

I have searched fruitlessly online for quite a while.
I have also restarted the TC server and build agents to no avail.

Any form of help will be very much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: You can accept your own answers, too. If you want. It might also be helpful to edit your answer to include the version you upgraded to.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to have been cause by the wrong ChromeDriver version been installed on the TeamCity server (screenshot attached).

[image]